# How to hit YouTube upload video api in command line ubuntu

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I want to upload multiple videos to Youtube through YouTube Data API v3.Well i have created the script and it runs smoothly through browser.

But i want to hit the YouTube Data API v3 through command line is there any way of doing that.

Here is main script.

```
<?php
    set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'YoutubeAPI');
    //require_once 'GoogleClientApi/src/Google/autoload.php';
    require_once 'Google/Client.php';
    require_once 'Google/Service/YouTube.php';
    session_start();


    $OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID = 'My Client ID';
    $OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET = 'Client Secret';

    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setClientId($OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID);
    $client->setClientSecret($OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET);
    $client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube');
    $redirect = filter_var('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
    $client->setRedirectUri($redirect);

    // Define an object that will be used to make all API requests.
    $youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);

    if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
        if (strval($_SESSION['state']) !== strval($_GET['state'])) {
            die('The session state did not match.');
        }
        $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
        $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
        header('Location: ' . $redirect);
    }
    if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
        $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
    }

    // Check to ensure that the access token was successfully acquired.
    if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
        try {
            // REPLACE this value with the path to the file you are uploading.
            $videoPath = "Video/naat.mp4";

            // Create a snippet with title, description, tags and category ID
            // Create an asset resource and set its snippet metadata and type.
            // This example sets the video's title, description, keyword tags, and
            // video category.
            $snippet = new Google_Service_YouTube_VideoSnippet();
            $snippet->setTitle("Test title");
            $snippet->setDescription("Test description");
            $snippet->setTags(array("tag1", "tag2"));

            // Numeric video category. See
            // https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list 
            $snippet->setCategoryId("22");

            // Set the video's status to "public". Valid statuses are "public",
            // "private" and "unlisted".
            $status = new Google_Service_YouTube_VideoStatus();
            $status->privacyStatus = "public";

            // Associate the snippet and status objects with a new video resource.
            $video = new Google_Service_YouTube_Video();
            $video->setSnippet($snippet);
            $video->setStatus($status);

            // Specify the size of each chunk of data, in bytes. Set a higher value for
            // reliable connection as fewer chunks lead to faster uploads. Set a lower
            // value for better recovery on less reliable connections.
            $chunkSizeBytes = 1 * 1024 * 1024;

            // Setting the defer flag to true tells the client to return a request which can be called
            // with ->execute(); instead of making the API call immediately.
            $client->setDefer(true);

            // Create a request for the API's videos.insert method to create and upload the video.
            $insertRequest = $youtube->videos->insert("status,snippet", $video);

            // Create a MediaFileUpload object for resumable uploads.
            $media = new Google_Http_MediaFileUpload(
                    $client, $insertRequest, 'video/*', null, true, $chunkSizeBytes
            );
            $media->setFileSize(filesize($videoPath));


            // Read the media file and upload it chunk by chunk.
            $status = false;
            $handle = fopen($videoPath, "rb");
            while (!$status && !feof($handle)) {
                $chunk = fread($handle, $chunkSizeBytes);
                $status = $media->nextChunk($chunk);
            }

            fclose($handle);

            // If you want to make other calls after the file upload, set setDefer back to false
            $client->setDefer(false);


            $htmlBody .= "<h3>Video Uploaded</h3><ul>";
            $htmlBody .= sprintf('<li>%s (%s)</li>', $status['snippet']['title'], $status['id']);

            $htmlBody .= '</ul>';
        } catch (Google_Service_Exception $e) {
            $htmlBody .= sprintf('<p>A service error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>', htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
        } catch (Google_Exception $e) {
            $htmlBody .= sprintf('<p>An client error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>', htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
        }

        $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    } else {
        // If the user hasn't authorized the app, initiate the OAuth flow
        $state = mt_rand();
        $client->setState($state);
        $_SESSION['state'] = $state;

        $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
        $htmlBody = <<<END
      <h3>Authorization Required</h3>
      <p>You need to <a href="$authUrl">authorize access</a> before proceeding.<p>
    END;
    }
    ?>

    <!doctype html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Video Uploaded</title>
        </head>
        <body>
    <?= $htmlBody ?>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: This looks more like `PHP` than "Ubuntu". Or is the question about trying to run the API outside of PHP, in which case, the answer is to use ANY programming language apart from PHP.

Comment: Actually the question is not to run API outside of php what i want to hit the above srcript by terminal so that i can create a cron job of that

Comment: You could just `CURL` your own server.